# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSessionContext with Spring Boot 3 and Jetty server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jetty, embedded-jetty

I community, I'm trying to run a small example with Spring boot 3 and Jetty server before upgrading the production code but I'm getting this error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSessionContext` and the services does not start. This is my Gradle config.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

idea {
    module {
        downloadJavadoc = false
        downloadSources = false
    }
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty'
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    }

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

and the dependeincies.

[image: dependencies]

HttpSessionContext class no longer exists but somehow, the latest version Jetty still depends on it.

I'm expecting to make it run with Jetty without migrating to another server.

Comment: Checkout this post. It explains for both Maven and Gradle. https://youtu.be/1gEoiMVULt4

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Update 23.12.13

No workaround needed anymore as Jetty [released version 12](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/rt.jetty/releases/12.0) with support for servlet 6.0.0.
So just update to spring-boot 3.2.0 (spring-boot-starter-jetty:3.2.0) which includes jetty 12.

### Origin

As Jaokim Erdfelt already [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74950099/11247654), Spring Boot 3 rely on Jakarta Servlet 6.0.0 (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Release-Notes) and the spring-boot-starter-jetty includes Jetty 11 which is build on Jakarta Servlet 5.0.0 (see https://java.libhunt.com/jetty-project-changelog/11.0.0). So this is an Issue in the starter itself.

To use jetty you have to downgrade the jakarta-servlet version (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#jetty) setting

```
ext["jakarta-servlet.version"] = "5.0.0"
```

Comment: thanks mathze, this is a big mistake from the spring team. Looks that they didn't test it :(

Comment: Wouldn't say it's a mistake. But maybe spring-team could had make this information better visible in their documentation ;)

Comment: For me, it's a mistake, because the starter dependencies are wrong. jetty starter must use Jakarta 5.0 and not the 6.0

Comment: I agree with @red. You can see in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jetty/3.0.2  that they declared spring-boot-starter-jetty:3.0.2 to depend on jakarta.servlet-api:6.0.0 and org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-*:11.0.13 and they are not compatible.

On a related note, for those using Maven, simply declared a property in your om.xml like this one:  
`<jakarta-servlet.version>5.0.0</jakarta-servlet.version>`  
and that's it.

Comment: if you downgrade to jakarta-servlet 5.0.0 then spring-test 6 doesn't compile anymore :)

Answer (score 9):

Just wanted to share my experience with Spring Boot 3 and Java 17. I recently encountered an issue with my pom.xml while working on a project. However, I was able to resolve it by making a few adjustments.

To fix the problem, I excluded Tomcat from the **spring-boot-starter-web** dependency and instead added **spring-boot-starter-jetty** to my project. However, I noticed that Maven was not able to fetch the necessary dependency automatically.

To overcome this, I added the **jakarta-servlet.version** property with a value of 5 in my pom.xml properties file. This ensured that Maven correctly resolved the required dependency.

If you're facing a similar issue, you can try out the following pom.xml configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<!-- Add this property -->
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <jakarta-servlet.version>5.0.0</jakarta-servlet.version>
</properties>

<!-- Exclude Tomcat and add Jetty -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions or if there's anything else I can assist you with.

Happy coding! ‍

Comment: That was the only part missing from all the other searches results
`<jakarta-servlet.version>5.0.0</jakarta-servlet.version>` at least for now

Comment: Exactly, this is the missing property "jakarta-servlet.version".

Answer (score 8):

For Spring Boot 3 and Jetty, you need a couple of dependencies.

- need the `jakarta.servlet-api`
- need the `jetty-server`
- need the `spring-boot-starter-jetty`

here is an example along with the versions

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

Add this line to your pom.xml properties:

```xml
<jakarta-servlet.version>5.0.0</jakarta-servlet.version>
```

Answer (score 3):

Spring 3 is for Servlet 6 which is available in Jetty 12+

Answer (score 0):

Pinning the version like

```
ext {
    set("jakarta-servlet.version", '5.0.0')
}
```

**did not worked** for me, using Spring Boot 3.1.5!

What helps at my side, is to strictly set the version using an implementation constraint:

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty") {
    constraints {
        implementation("jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api") {
            version {
                strictly("5.0.0")
                prefer("5.0.0")
            }
            because("Jetty 11.x requires jakarta.servlet-api 5.0.0 where version 6.0.0 is bundled with spring-boot-starter-jetty (Spring Boot 3.1.5)!")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Spring boot 3.x onward extra jetty-server dependancy is needed...**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```