class path resource [jakarta/servlet/Filter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
I am getting below error when running my spring boot application. Spring boot version is 3.3.1 and JDK version 21.
Error:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: I/O failure while processing configuration class [com.example.otrs.Service.CORSFilter]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [jakarta/servlet/Filter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist.
My pom.xml:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>otrs</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>otrs</name>
    <description>OTRS Project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>4.0.1</version>-->
<!--            <scope>provided</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

My application.properties file:
spring.application.name=otrs
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3301/otrs
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=ishu@1007

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl.auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect


non anonymized database credentials are in this code snippet. CreadetialsExposureException.

Y tried with
<dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

and the error change to:
Web application could not be started as there was no org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory bean defined in the context.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

the combination is Spring boot 3.2.0, servlets V6.0.0, resolved SpringFramework 6.1.1 and Jetty 12. As @Joakim Erdfelt pointed in an answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74946784/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-jakarta-servlet-http-httpsessioncontext-with-s/74950613.

Can you please remove the provided scope from the jakarta dependency?

I changed the scope from "provided" to "compile" and removed the scope of spring-boot-starter-tomcat library and problem solved.

I think you don't need to change the provided scope to compile, but you can keep it, because it comes from the spring-boot-dependencies parent as a transitive dependency. source: https://github.com/mahendra-shinde/maven-repo-springboot/blob/master/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.1.6.RELEASE.pom

You can try with Changing jakarta.servlet-api version to 5.0.1. And remove scope of spring-boot-starter-tomcat library.

there is no such one https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api
